# How can I request an https api in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, https

I have a simple ajax request:

```
$.ajax({url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=stuff&callback=JSON_CALLBACK',success: function(data){
console.log(data);
}});
```

When I manually open the link, I get the object I want, but not through an ajax request. The thing is, if the api address is http it works. Can so tell me why that is and how I get around it?

Comment: this should be is `$.get`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily manage with `get`: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

```
$.get( "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=stuff&callback=JSON_CALLBACK", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: If you try this you'll see a 'No Access Control header' error in the console

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should send a GET request, not a POST. However a bigger issue is that you need to retrieve JSONP data, not JSON.

To do this you can use `$.ajax()` with the appropriate settings:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=stuff',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember to specify that you are using JSONP.

```js
$.ajax({
 url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=stuff&callback=?',
 success: function(data){
  console.log(data);
 },
 dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'jsonp' as the option for datatype to your ajax settings, like here:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search& gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=stuff&callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: Do be clear, you can use $get as well, but it is just a shorthand version of:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

$ajax is using 'GET' as the default request method.